# How does a cracked pale green prism ioun stone work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

A cracked [pale green prism](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/pale-green-prism-ioun-stone) says

> This stone grants a +1 competence bonus on attack rolls or saving throws.

...Whereas the uncracked standard version says

> This stone grants the wearer a +1 competence bonus on attack rolls, saves, skill checks, and ability checks.

Does the cracked stone grant:

1. +1 competence to both attack rolls and saves?
2. +1 competence to either attack rolls or saves (switchable in some fashion by the user)?
3. +1 competence to either attack rolls or saves (determined at creation and then unchangeable)?
4. ...or something else?

Due to the use of *and* for the standard (30,000GP) item and the use of *or* for the cracked (4,000GP) item, I find #1 highly unlikely. I could imagine #2, but my hunch would be that it's #3.

Comment: [Related] [Can one benefit from two of the same ioun stone with alternative bonuses?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91697)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**I would go with the effect being a +1 competence to either attack rolls OR saves (determined at creation and then unchangeable).**

My first supporting reason is, that's what it says.  So, taking the text at face value, this is the simplest solution.  No second guessing required.

Second, d20PFSRD is good about correcting typos.  This is not a new section so it is fair to say that any typos would have been noted by now.  I admit it's not 100% but with past responses to typos being as quick as they have, I'd say it is fair to say that bit of text in the d20PFSRD is ok as it is.

Finally, the cost.  As you noted, 4000 gold is low for something that would give both benefits.  Hence, it is likely that only one of the two is in effect. That brings the cost more inline with the effect.

As to why I say it would be determined at creation and not switchable at any time?  The nature of the [Inferior Ioun Stones](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones#TOC-Inferior-Ioun-Stones).  These are magic items with a fault of some kind.  Either they were made poorly or suffered some damage.  It could be argued that you can't change that fault/damage on demand, it just "is".

Backing up that assertion, [Seekers of Secrets](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Seekers_of_Secrets,_A_Guide_to_the_Pathfinder_Society), the text that introduces inferior ioun stones (including this one), says (p46),

> "For stones that have multiple possible effects…, the exact effect is
>   determined by the item crafter when it is created and cannot be
>   changed thereafter"

Thank you [Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/8610/hey-i-can-chan) for the note on that.

Comment: *Seekers of Secrets*, the text that introduces inferior *ioun stones* (including this one), says, "For *stones* that have multiple possible effects…, the exact effect is determined by the item crafter when it is created and cannot be changed thereafter" (46).

Comment: If we will consider the cost, then the stone should cost about 2000 gp instead of 4000 gp according to the item creation tables. No?

Comment: Actually, the price is correct. Save Bonus (Other) is used here since it isnt resistance bonus. +1 * 2000 is 2000, double for a slotless item.

Comment: +1 for semantics. Addition: solution 1 is not possible as this is worded in a way that makes clear it is an exclusive or. Similarly, any item's magic effects are set at creation and can not be changed. (look at headband of intelligence) So 3 is out of question too.